# structs in .h not working if .h included in more than one .cpp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, struct, header

I want to use this callbacks object in more than one .cpp, but VS gives "one or more multiply defined symbols found" error if I include more than once.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

typedef struct {
void(__cdecl *callbackOne)(bool val);
void(__cdecl *callbackTwo)(bool val);
void(__cdecl *callbackThree)(bool val);
} Callbacks;
Callbacks callbacks;

#endif
```

Comment: You should read about the differences between _decleration_ and _definition_

Comment: Think about this: when you include your header in multiple source files, you copy the header content (once) into them. Multiple struct **descriptions** aren't a problem, but **object** `callbacks` because this is globally visible and linking the object files finds this conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Callbacks callbacks;
```

This is a **definition**. Since `#include` works like textual substitution, in each source file that includes your header there will be a (separate, different) instance of your structure defined.

Thus, when finally linking the compiled object files together, each of them contains an own instance and the associated symbol `callbacks`, resulting in the described linker error.

To have a single instance of your structure, you need to put the above definition into a single source file.

To be able to use that instance from other source files, they need to be able to refer to it ("know it's name"). That's the purpose of a **declaration** ("give a name "):

```
extern Callbacks callbacks;
```

This is what you need to put into your header.

Comment: `extern Callbacks callbacks;` in my header and `typedef struct {...} Callbacks;
Callbacks callbacks;` in my source file seems to cause an error of redefinition with callbacks

Comment: Who told you to put `typedef struct ...` in your source file? Put the typedef in the header file, put `extern Callbacks callbacks;` in the header file, put `Callbacks callbacks;` in the source file. If it still doesn't work then post your new code. Above all understand the difference between a definition and a declaration.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Declare in the header

```
extern Callbacks callbacks;
```

and define the object in some cpp file.

```
Callbacks callbacks;
```

Otherwise you have as many definitions of the object as many cpp files include this header.

Comment: `error C2086: 'int callbacks' : redefinition` I get this error defining the object in some cpp file

Comment: @theman It only means that you also defined the object in some other cpp file. You should do as I described.